# Cannot convert WhereListIterator

Tags: c#, linq

I want to filter a list by a given List of Ids, that the item should 'be in'

```
 // list is of type List<BaseModel>
 // so item is of type BaseModel
 // item.Id is of type ushort
 // filter.IdIn is of type List<ushort>

 List<BaseModel> filtered = (List<BaseModel>)
                  from item in list
                  where filter.IdIn.Contains(item.Id)
                  select item;
```

This throws the error (translated from german to english by me - silly me installed VisualStudio in german..):

> System.InvalidCastException: 'The Object of type
>   "WhereListIterator`1[JeffData.BaseModel]" can not be converted to
>   "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JeffData.BaseModel]" '

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537528/how-to-convert-system-linq-enumerable-wherelistiteratorint-to-listint) I've tried changing to

```
List<BaseModel> filtered = (List<BaseModel>)
                  from item in list
                  where filter.IdIn.ToList().Contains(item.Id)
                  select item;
```

and

```
List<BaseModel> filtered = (List<BaseModel>) list.Where(item =>  
                        filter.IdIn.ToList().Contains(item.Id)
                        );

// with or without ToList()
```

It will all throw the same error.
When I don't try to Cast it to List,

```
var filtered = list.Where(item => filter.IdIn.Contains(item.Id));
```

no error is thrown (because it wont compile) and `filtered` will just be a 'WhereListIterator' and I cannot return it

```
return filtered; // as a List<BaseModel>
```

Getting back a WhereListIterator made me think I might need to do it the other way round. Don't check if `filter.IdIn.Contains(item.Id)` but check if `item.Id is in/partof/memberof filter.IdIn`, but this doesn't seem to exist!?

So **boiled down**:
I have a list of items that have an ushort Id. I wanna find the items which Ids are in a List of ushort Ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about WhereListIterator (not sure if that's part of the translation)

I'd expect the Where() to return an IEnumerable which would not cast to a list.

that's where ToList() will resolve the enumerable for you though.

```
var filtered = list.Where(item => filter.IdIn.Contains(item.Id)).ToList();
```

or if you prefer:

```
var filtered = (from item in list
              where filter.IdIn.ToList().Contains(item.Id)
              select item).ToList();
```

Comment: The `WhereListIterator` is not translated, that's original. Thanks for the answer, I'll check that out!

Comment: `WhereListIterator` is the internal class that handles Where operations for Lists

Comment: Yes, that looks good!! Compiling and running without errors. Thank you very much!